# Facebook can't download og:image from host

Tags: drupal-7, share, facebook-opengraph

After migrating a website I created from one host to another, the problem occured:

Facebook is unable to get the og:image when I go and share. This was not the case on the former host.

**Some info about the site:**

- It's ran on Drupal 7.14
- Both site are identical, .htaccess files
  included.

**Things I already found while looking for the problem**

- HTTPS problem
- .htaccess: Options FollowSymLinks
- Picture aspect ratio < 3:1

None of the above solutions have worked.

Running the website through Facebook linter i get the error:
Unable to download og:image: The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded.

I also ran it through OpenGraph checker, nothing wrong here!
http://ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/index.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bikinicontest.be%2Fbabe%2Fjana-claus

You can find the page here: http://www.bikinicontest.be

Answer (score 2):

According to [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) you have a circular redirect path on that page:

```
original    http://www.bikinicontest.be/
og:url  http://www.bikinicontest.be/home
301 http://www.bikinicontest.be/
```

Try fixing that first

If that doesn't fix it, it may be a problem with the image file itself , or a bug with Facebook's crawler - in which case you should file a bug report in the [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in the facebook crawler since I still have the test environment running at which it does work.

Comment: You’re right, it’s _not_ a bug in the debug tool, but on your site. So go & fix it.